# Why was Fred Bear shooting left-handed?

Tags: archery, bow-hunting

Fred Bear was right-handed and, as far as I know, his dominant eye was also the right one.

[image: Left-handed]
[image: Left-handed]
[image: Left-handed]
[image: Left-handed]

Nevertheless he shot left-handed - why?

Comment: Was the shoot staged? Was he actually shooting or just posing for a photo? Has the photo been mirrored (it's common for photo's to be edited to reverse the photo if it fits a design better)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having done a bit of googling it appears he appears he shot left-handed due to an accident where he had part of one of his fingers amputated:

> ...Fred Bear shot the bow left handed, but he was right eye dominant.
>   **He had a partial amputation of one of the fingers on his right hand**, so it was either draw left handed or only draw with two
>   fingers of his right hand. Everything else he did right handed,
>   including shotgun shooting.

### [Source](http://www.tradbow.com/public/Dominant-Eye-Follow-Up.cfm)

this also appears to explain why in earlier photos he shoots right-handed. He switched after losing his finger (*I'm reading between the lines here a little*)